# Implement navigation in image slider

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I would like to implement a simple left and right arrow navigation into an image slider. Below is what I have already tried. Where do I have to place the function if I click on an arrow. Inside or outside the `changeImg` function? Thanks in advance

```
    <div class="slider">
        <span id="left">&lt</span>
        <img class="sliderImg" name="slide">
        <span id="right">&gt</span>
    </div>

    var i = 0;
    var images = [];
    var time = 4000;

    images[0] = "img/image1.png";
    images[1] = "img/image2.png";
    images[2] = "img/image3.png";

    function changeImg() {
        document.slide.src = images[i];

        if (i < images.length - 1) {
            i++;
        }

        document.querySelector("#left").addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            i--;
        });

        else {
            i = 0;
        }
        setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    }
```

Comment: you'll need to made way more changes than placing the changeImg() inside or outside

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img alt="slideshow" src="img/image1.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" />
    </div>
    <span id="left-arrow">left</span>
      <span id="right-arrow">right</span>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var imgs = ["img/image2.png", "img/image3.png", "img/image4.png"];

    function changeImage(dir) {
        var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
        img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
    }

    var left=document.getElementById('left-arrow');
   var right=document.getElementById('right-arrow');
    left.onclick = function(e) {

            changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image

    }
     right.onclick = function(e) {

            changeImage() //left <- show Prev image

    }
```

Use your correct path to your images